# How to calculate variance-covariance matrix from a multivariate sample of probabilities?

Tags: r, covariance-matrix, lognormal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a 21 x 3 matrix of probabilities (values between 0 and 1). I would like to get estimates of multivariate **log**-normal variances and covariances.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in R or SAS?

I was using the following formulas to get the univariate estimates of variance for each column based on the normal mean and sd, but I would like the covariances (I apologize for not speaking LaTex):

mz = mean of lognormal variate, sz= sd of lognormal variate, mx = mean of normal variate, sx= sd of normal variate

mz= exp(mx)exp(sx^2/2)

sz = mz[esp(sz^2)-1]^0.5

lognormal var = sz^2

Extending this to a multivariate scenario is lost on me and I'm not even sure if the above is appropriate to apply to a vector of probabilities since they are bounded on 0 and 1.

Comment: The above is not appropriate. The log normal can take on any positive value. You may want to try and use the beta distribution. To extend it to a MV framework, use copulas.

Comment: Well, the end point (answer) must be on the log normal scale. So it is a question of how to get there, rather than changing where "there" is.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is the answer:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Multivariate_log-normal